# How do I code date / time into a WIX site embed feature?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to this and have worked some things out but this one has got me. I am trying to embed a code into a WIX site (HTML then Javascript) so text appears that is dependant on the day (ddd) and hour. It is for a local radio station, so for example if it is Monday at 14:00 to 16:00 it's the local news, so the box would say "Live Now - Local News".

I have tried all the codes I can find on here but nothing works. Is anyone able to help me please?

Thank you in advance

This is the code I have so far that doesn't work

```
<script> 

var hour = getHours() 
var day = getDay() 
document.onload=function timechange() { 

if day==1 && hour>17 && hour<18 
</script> 
<body> 
<h1>Phatsoundz Radio Presents : </h1> 
<script>
```

Comment: This is the code I'm using but the "If" element isn't working.

Comment: <script>
  
var hour = getHours()
var day = getDay()

document.onload=function timechange() {

if day==1 && hour>17 && hour<18
    
</script>
<body>
<h1>Phatsoundz Radio Presents : </h1>
<script>

Comment: HI and welcome. Make sure to edit your question to add the necessary code there.

Comment: Thank you, apologies, I have done now.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example that will display the **Live Now - Local News** block if it is Tuesday and the hour is between 1200 & 1800 (6pm):

```
<html>
    <body> 
        <h1>Phatsoundz Radio Presents : </h1> 
        <div id="liveNowLocalNews" style="display:none">Live Now - Local News</div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var today = new Date();
        var hour  = today.getHours();
        var day   = today.getDay();

        if ((day === 2) && (hour > 12) && (hour < 18)) {
            document.getElementById('liveNowLocalNews').style.display = "block";
        }
    </script> 
</html>
```